# how to add image with table header?

Tags: php, html, mysql, pagination

How I can show three images at different time with the table header. I have a code fro table header along with the links to show data in ascending and descending and filters on them.

```
echo "<table  width='100%'>

   <tr>
     <th><a href= 'http://192.168.0.49/intern/index.php?page=".$_GET["page"]."&date1=".$_GET["date1"]."&date2=".$_GET["date2"].         "&orderby=id&dir=".$dir."'>Id</th>
     <th><a href= 'http://192.168.0.49/intern/index.php?page=".$_GET["page"]."&date1=".$_GET["date1"]."&date2=".$_GET["date2"]."&orderby=event_date&dir=".$dir."'>Event Date</a></th>
     <th><a href= 'http://192.168.0.49/intern/index.php?page=".$_GET["page"]."&date1=".$_GET["date1"]."&date2=".$_GET["date2"]."&orderby=bdm_name&dir=".$dir."'>BDM Name</th>
     <th><a href= 'http://192.168.0.49/intern/index.php?page=".$_GET["page"]."&date1=".$_GET["date1"]."&date2=".$_GET["date2"]."&orderby=event_type&dir=".$dir."'>Event Performed</th>
     <th><a href= 'http://192.168.0.49/intern/index.php?page=".$_GET["page"]."&date1=".$_GET["date1"]."&date2=".$_GET["date2"]."&orderby=completed&dir=".$dir."'>Completed</th>
   </tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . date( "m/d/Y", strtotime($row['event_date'])) . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['bdm_name'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['event_type'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['completed'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
 echo "</table>";
```

And I use conditions

```
if (!$link) 
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
if($_REQUEST["dir"]=="" || $_REQUEST["dir"]=="desc")
$dir="asc";
else
$dir="desc";

  if($_REQUEST["orderby"]!="")$ord = " ORDER BY ".$_REQUEST["orderby"];
  if($_REQUEST["dir"]!="")$ord .= " ".$_REQUEST["dir"];
```

And for pagination I use:

```
$page = (intval($_GET['page'])>0) ? $_GET['page'] : 2;
$recordPerPage= '30';
$startPoint = ($page - 1)*$recordPerPage;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) cnt FROM ` admin_crmf_poc_event_history` where $condition");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $num_rows = $row["cnt"];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ` admin_crmf_poc_event_history` where $condition $ord LIMIT $startPoint,$recordPerPage");
        $totalPages=ceil($num_rows/$recordPerPage);
```

And images which I want to add are look like [image] for desc [image] for asc and [image] for no action. such that if I click on header link for desc, desc image will show and same phenomena for asc and other header links which are not clicked shows the image of no action.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have all of the data you need to conditionally show images using the values.  For each of your headers, you can simply add the correct image conditionally.

Such as

```
$headings = array(
    'id'         => 'Id',
    'event_date' => 'Event Date',
    'bdm_name'   => 'BDM Name',
    'event_type' => 'Event Performed',
    'completed'  => 'Completed'
);

$actionImages = array(
    'noaction' => 'noaction.png',
    'asc'  => 'ascending.png',
    'desc' => 'descending.png',
);

$currentDirection = $_REQUEST['dir'];
$defaultDirection = 'desc';
$orderByColumn    = $_REQUEST['orderby'];

echo '<table  width="100%"><tr>';

// For each heading, add to table
foreach ($headings as $column => $label) {
    // Determine action image to show
    if ($orderByColumn == $column) {
        $actionImg = (!empty($currentDirection)) ? $actionImages[$currentDirection] : $actionImages[$defaultDirection];
    } else {
        $actionImg = $actionImages['noaction'];
    }

    echo '<th><img src="' . $actionImg . '">'
        . '<a href="http://192.168.0.49/intern/index.php?page='
        . $_GET['page'] . '&date1=' . $_GET['date1'] . '&date2=' . $_GET['date2']
        . '&orderby=' . $column . '&dir=' . $dir . '">'
        . $label . '</th>';
}

echo '</tr>';
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should give you an idea of how to accomplish what you're looking for.